# How do i add Limit of word count in shopify schema option?

Tags: html, css, shopify

How do i add a word count limit option in schema textarea or richtext element in shopify schema settings

```
{
"type":"textarea",
"id":"note1",
"label":"Custom Note I",
"default":"A cookie for the person the world needs more of.",
"limit":100
},
```

Comment: hi! you can add  maxlength="255" in text area tag.

Answer (score 0):

**For Textarea**

```json
{
  "type": "textarea",
  "id": "description",
  "label": "Description",
  "default": "",
  "info": "Please limit your description to 500 characters.",
  "validation": {
    "max-length": 500,
    "required": false
  }
}
```

Note: The `max_length` attribute measures the length of the input in characters, not words.

Comment: 'max_length' is not a valid attribute

Comment: I really appreciate your answe. But it's still showing same error like 'validation' is not a valid attribute

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vztkPt4-_1ho

Comment: This is the default parameter you pass to the text area, there are no validation attributes to Shopify liquid code.

Comment: You need to developed frontend logic using JS code for this.